# Setting a label background colour to transparent in WinForms make it ignore any images underneath it and displays the form background image instead

Tags: c#, winforms, background, label, panel

I'm working on a very image intensive application.

In this example, there is a Panel at the very back with a background image and a PictureBox ontop of that with a background image. When I add a label ontop of that and set the background colour to be transparent, the background colour displayed is of the Panel background image and it completely ignores the image that's in between the two. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how transparency works in Windows Forms. It's fake. A transparent control isn't actually transparent and allowing what's behind it to show through. Instead, it just draws a copy of its parent in its own background. If you want a `PictureBox` to show through a `Label` then the `Label` has to actually be a child of the `PictureBox`. The catch is that you cannot do that in the designer, so you have to add the `Label` to some other container and then move it to the `PictureBox` in code. I suggest that you place the `Label` in the exact location you want it in the designer, regardless of its parent container. You can then do this in the `Load` event handler of your form:

```cs
label1.Location = pictureBox1.PointToClient(label1.PointToScreen(Point.Empty));
label1.Parent = pictureBox1;
```

That code gets the location of the `Label` relative to the screen, then translates that to a `Point` relative to the `PictureBox` and assigns that to the `Location` of the `Label`. When the `Label` is added to the `PictureBox`, it appears at that location, so in the exact same location it was to start with, only inside the `PictureBox`.

Here's an extension method that does the same thing:

```cs
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void SetParentWithSameScreenCoordinates(this Control source, Control parent)
    {
        source.Location = parent.PointToClient(source.PointToScreen(Point.Empty));
        source.Parent = parent;
    }
}
```

You can then do this in your `Load` event handler:

```cs
label1.SetParentWithSameScreenCoordinates(pictureBox1);
```

Comment: That's absolutely insane but it works, thank you.